# Why is a generic typed property nullable?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to create a parameterized class with a `lateinit` non-nullable property of the generic type:

```
class Test<T> {

   private lateinit var t : T

   private lateinit var s : String

}
```

The latter is allowed, but the former is not. The compiler returns the following error:

> Error:(7, 11) ''lateinit'' modifier is not allowed on nullable properties

Since I didn't declare `T?`, I am confused as to why this is the case.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

> The default upper bound (if none specified) is `Any?` ([Source](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-constraints))

In other words, when you use `T`, Kotlin assumes that this might be *any* type, be it primitive, object or a nullable reference.

To fix this add an upper type:

```
class Test<T: Any> { ... }
```

Comment: and BTW, syntax `T?` is not allowed, so technically there is NO inconsistency.

Comment: `T?` is allowed in the use of `T`, not the declaration of `T`.   So `val x: T?` is valid.

Comment: You can read more on T? here https://medium.com/@igorwojda/kotlin-deep-dive-into-generics-nullability-9853d9a9f50d

Answer (score 12):

### Nullable Type Parameter

`Any?` is the supertype of *all* types in Kotlin. So, when you don't specify any upper bound for the type parameter `T`, the default bound is `Any?`.

For example:

`class Test<T> { }`

is the same as

`class Test<T : Any?> { }`

This results in the `T` being nullable in the following example:

```
class Test<T> {
    private var t : T          // T can have a nullable type
}
```

This means that the generic type above can be instantiated with nullable as well as non-null type arguments:

```
val test: Test<Int> = Test()   // OK
val test: Test<Int?> = Test()  // OK
```

---

### Non-null Type Parameter

`Any` is the supertype of *all non-null* types in Kotlin. So, to make a generic class accept only non-null type arguments, you need to explicitly specify `Any` as an upper bound of `T`, that is `T : Any`.

This results in the `T` being non-null in the following example:

```
class Test<T : Any> {
    private var t: T           // T is non-null
    private var t2: T?         // T can be used as nullable
}
```

The generic type with `T : Any` can be instantiated only with non-null type arguments and prevents the instantiation with nullable type arguments:

```
val test: Test<Int> = Test()   // OK
val test: Test<Int?> = Test()  // Error
```

---

### `lateinit var`

The `lateinit var` must always be non-null because it is used in the cases where you want a variable to be non-null but don't want to initialize its value at the time of object creation.

So, to create the `lateinit` variable that has the same type as the type parameter `T`, the type parameter needs to be non-null too.

To achieve that, specify the upper bound `T : Any` explicitly:

```
class Test<T : Any> {
    private lateinit var t: T
}
```

It's worth noting that you can use a more specific type, if you have one depending on your business logic. For example, instead of `T : Any`, you could have `T : SomeProduct`, if that is what you want the upper bound to be. It just needs to be non-null.

This will ensure that the user of your class won't be able to instantiate with nullable type arguments and your assumption of the `lateinit var` always being non-null will hold true.

---

That's it! Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

[Kotlin In Action](https://www.manning.com/books/kotlin-in-action) has following to say on nullability of type parameters

> Nullability of type parameters:
>
> By default, all type parameters of
>   functions and classes in Kotlin are nullable. Any type, including a
>   nullable type, can be substituted for a type parameter; in this case,
>   declarations using the type parameter as a type are allowed to be
>   null, even though the type parameter T doesn’t end with a question
>   mark.

How to make type parameters not-null?

> To make the type parameter non-null, you need to specify a non-null
>   upper bound for it. That will reject a nullable value as an argument.
>
> Note that type parameters are the only exception to the rule that a
>   question mark at the end is required to mark a type as nullable, and
>   types without a question mark are non-null. The next section shows
>   another special case of nullability: types that come from the Java
>   code.

Answer (score 0):

T, when used as a type parameter, is always null. (All type parameters are nullable). You don't need to declare `T?`, only `T` is needed. To use declare an upper bound, do this `public class Foo<T: Any>` (`Any` isn't nullable)

Answer (score 0):

When adding [Platform Types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html) in the mix, it even gets more fun

```kotlin
data class Dto(
    val ids: List<UUID>
)
```

that is why you can do

```kotlin
        val ids  = arrayListOf(UUID.randomUUID()) // ArrayList<UUID!> inferred 
ids.add(null)
val body = Dto(ids = ids)
```

but not

```kotlin
val ids : ArrayList<UUID?>  = arrayListOf(UUID.randomUUID())
ids.add(null)
val body = Dto(ids = ids)
```

```kotlin
public fun <T> arrayListOf(vararg elements: T): kotlin.collections.ArrayList<T> /* = java.util.ArrayList<T> */
typealias ArrayList<E> = java.util.ArrayList<E>
```

it's just a typealias for java type `ArrayList<E>`

[image: platform type]

`UUID!` indicated that it is a [platform type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html)

or? https://pl.kotl.in/U-5aHGBWK